# What is the type of a Kotlin 'data class'?

Tags: kotlin

I have a situation where I need to create a copy of data class object. I don't know in advance which of the many data classes I have will come in into the function. I do know, however, that only data classes will be used as input to this function.

This is what didn't work:

```
fun doSomething(obj: Any): Any {
  obj.copy(...) // <- there's no 'copy' on Any
  ...
}
```

This is what I really like to do:

```
fun doSomething(obj: KAnyDataClass): KAnyDataClass {
  obj.copy(...) // <- works, data classes have a 'copy' method
  ...
}
```

Comment: There is no data class supertype. Even if there was, it'd be of no use, as the copy function depends on the concrete data class constructor.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Kotlin developer, but it looks like the language [does not support dynamic dispatch or traits](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/multimethods-generic-functions/6033/5). You might find success with the [dynamic](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/dynamic-type.html) type, which just turns off the type-checker so it won't yell at you for using a method that it doesn't know about. However this opens up the possibility of a runtime error if you pass an argument that actually doesn't have that method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It seems that the `dynamic` type is not supported on the JVM, which is where my program runs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no class or interface for data classes, but we know from the [documentation of data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html) that there are derived functions `componentN` and `copy` in each data class.

We can use that knowledge to write an abstract copy method that calls the copy method of a given arbitrary data class using reflection:

```
fun <T : Any> copy(data: T, vararg override: Pair<Int, Any?>): T {
    val kClass = data::class
    if (!kClass.isData) error("expected a data class")
    val copyFun = kClass.functions.first { it.name == "copy" }
    checkParameters(override, kClass)
    val vals = determineComponentValues(copyFun, kClass, override, data)
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return copyFun.call(data, *vals) as T
}

/** check if override of parameter has the right type and nullability */
private fun <T : Any> checkParameters(
    override: Array<out Pair<Int, Any?>>,
    kClass: KClass<out T>
) {
    override.forEach { (index, value) ->
        val expectedType = kClass.functions.first { it.name == "component${index + 1}" }.returnType
        if (value == null) {
            if (!kClass.functions.first { it.name == "component${index + 1}" }.returnType.isMarkedNullable) {
                error("value for parameter $index is null but parameter is not nullable")
            }
        } else {
            if (!expectedType.jvmErasure.isSuperclassOf(value::class))
                error("wrong type for parameter $index: expected $expectedType but was ${value::class}")
        }
    }
}

/** determine for each componentN the value from override or data element */
private fun <T : Any> determineComponentValues(
    copyFun: KFunction<*>,
    kClass: KClass<out T>,
    override: Array<out Pair<Int, Any?>>,
    data: T
): Array<Any?> {
    val vals = (1 until copyFun.parameters.size)
        .map { "component$it" }
        .map { name -> kClass.functions.first { it.name == name } }
        .mapIndexed { index, component ->
            override.find { it.first == index }.let { if (it !== null) it.second else component.call(data) }
        }
        .toTypedArray()
    return vals
}
```

Since this `copy` function is generic and not for a specific data class, it is not possible to specify overloads in the usual way, but I tried to support it in another way.
Let's say we have a data class and element

```
data class Example(
    val a: Int,
    val b: String,
)

val example: Any = Example(1, "x")
```

We can create a copy of `example` with `copy(example)` that has the same elements as the original.

If we want to override the first element, we cannot write `copy(example, a = 2)`, but we can write `copy(example, 0 to 2)`, saying that we want to override the first component with value 2.

Analogously we can write `copy(example, 0 to 3, 1 to "y")` to specify that we want to change the first and the second component.

I am not sure if this works for all cases since I just wrote it, but it should be a good start to work with.